# Communication between 2 GSM 900A modems

Tags: gsm, modem

I am supposed to work on project which involves communication between 2 GSM 900A modems. The main idea is to acquire data in remote location through Arduino (Arduino Mega in my case) and transmitting the data to the Server which will be my laptop, in which that communication part i use 2 GSM 900A modems. I am new to GSM modems so could you please help me with your ideas for establishing communication between 2 modems..

Answer (score 2):

I posted a blog on this topic which is given below. I think it may be helpful for you. link:http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/category/embedded/

Answer (score 0):

GSM modems do not follow a common standard, although the command set does tend to be a superset of Hayes AT. You will need to refer to documentation and development kits for your particular devices.

Comment: What? GSM modems do by absolutely by all means follow a common standard for AT commands, or actually two: 3GPP 27.007 (mainly) and 27.005 (for a subset of the commands). Now, granted not every single behaviour of a phone/modem is standardized, but both circuit switched and packed switched data connections most certainly are.

Comment: @hlovdal I wasn't aware of the standards, but was speaking from having reviewed a few manuals of specific modems while evaluating vendors. This was a few years ago now, but I got the impression the parts weren't really interchangeable. Also, they weren't 3G devices, and I was focusing on SMS functionality. OP never mentioned what he's actually doing, besides "send data" on 900 MHz. :P